# Drag and Drop Text to C# Console Application exe

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Basically I want to start up a c# console application by selecting text from say a web page or word or something, drag the text over the c# application's .exe file, and retrieving the text in the console application.

So for example I select the word "Hello" from a webpage. I then drag it over the .exe icon for the c# project. The C# project then reads the "Hello" I dragged and dropped and does some processing to it.

I'm aware of how to drag and drop files in c# but the I cant copy text over the .exe icon. Is there a way to alter the properties of the project so it will accept text being dragged and dropped over it? Is what I want to do even possible?

The reason I wanted a console app was because I was trying to implement the functionality of a 3rd party library on text by just dragging the text over the applications icon.

Comment: Dragging and dropping is UI specific, so I doubt this will work with a console application.

Comment: Thats what I thought but just checking. I'll keep looking for a workaround for a bit before giving up I suppose.

Comment: Do you specifically need a console application? Because in the information you supplied, it doesn't state that you are not allowed to have a simple UI for the application.

Comment: No a UI wouldn't work for what I want. The reason I wanted a console app was because I was trying to implement the functionality of a 3rd party library on text by just dragging the text over the applications icon. Have decided to go a different route and add a shell command to execute a batch file on selected text.